# Как правильно писать "Формационно-ориентированные"?

Tags: грамматика

Не могу понять, как правильно писать слово «формационно-ориентированные» (теории права).
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, надо раздельно. Формационно ориентированные. 
Речь же идет об "ориентированных на формацию" теориях? Не "формационных и ориентированных"?

Да и вообще со словом "ориентированный" словарь дает только раздельные варианты:

демократически ориентированный
коммуникативно ориентированный
личностно ориентированный
машинно ориентированный
общественно ориентированный
объектно ориентированный
пакетно ориентированный